# Outlook. Add folder to favorites group

Tags: vba, outlook, favorites

I'm working now on Outlook macros to add selected folder to Outlook's favorites group.
I've tried to use this method

```
Sub AddToFavorites()
  Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
  Set objFolder = olapp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
  objFolder.AddToPFFavorites 
End Sub
```

But AddToPFFavorites method throws error "The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found".

I've tried to add target folder to favorites using "Show in Favorites" action from context menu, as result folder has been showed in Favorites group without errors.

My question is:
  How to add folder to favorites group? 
  What is VBA equivalent for "Show in Favorites" action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manage the Outlook **favorites group** by accessing the [`NavigationPane`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868233.aspx) mail module.

```cs
Outlook.MailModule mailModule = ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(Outlook.OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleMail) as Outlook.MailModule;
Outlook.NavigationGroup favGroup = mailModule.NavigationGroups.GetDefaultNavigationGroup(Outlook.OlGroupType.olFavoriteFoldersGroup);
favGroup.NavigationFolders.Add(objFolder);
```