# How to change the order of subfolders in navigation pane using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

In the navigation pane in Outlook 2016 I can right-click a sub-folder and select "move up" or "move down" to change the order.

I can't find the corresponding VBA command to do this. It's not in `Outlook.Folder` or `Outlook.View`.

```vb
Sub MoveToTop(newFolderName as String)
    Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim newFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim rootFolder as Outlook.Folder
  
    Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set rootFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set newFolder = rootFolder.Items.Find (newFolderName)

    'now I need something like:
    newFolder.MoveUp
End Sub
```

I am missing the link between the view in the navigation pane and the folders in the MAPI namespace.

Comment: Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868038/outlook-2013-outlook-2016-vba-rearrange-folders-in-folders-tree?rq=1), it seems like you need to manipulate the `PR_SORT_POSITION` property.

Comment: Thanks Raymond! This is a path I didn't even know existed until now. I am looking into it right now, trying to find the right property for my problem